# SQLite Disk IO error

Tags: sqlite

I get next issue, when access to DB (insert + ExecuteNonQuery()).
But I can execute SELECT FROM command, I am a bit confused(
here is exception code.

```
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException was unhandled
  _HResult=-2147467259
  _message=disk I/O error
disk I/O error
  HResult=-2147467259
  IsTransient=false
  Message=disk I/O error
```

Comment: Is your disk full?  Is it corrupted?  Is it fragmented?  What OS and file system are you running on?

Answer (score -1):

Check permissions. You need write permission to perform updates/inserts/etc.

Comment: Seems like yes,  i  have moved DB to disk D, and it helped. But, there is a need to run app, when db on disk D.

Comment: Maybe you could post the permissions of the file/directory. Pretty sure you only have to sort out the permissions for it to work.